# How can I get data from a table using phpQuery in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table, phpquery

I would like to get the text on tr 2, td 4, first a, from every article (table), I must not be linking to the text right as when I `print_r` I don't get anything displayed back.

```
// table 1
      <table class="articles">
         <tbody>
           <tr>some text here maybe tags</tr>
           <tr>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td><a href="link.html">WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</a></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>   

      </table> 

// table 2
      <table class="articles">
         <tbody>
           <tr>some text here maybe tags</tr>
           <tr>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td><a href="link.html">WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</a></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>   

      </table>

// more tables etc.

      <table class="articles">
         <tbody>
           <tr>some text here maybe tags</tr>
           <tr>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td><a href="link.html">WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</a></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>   

      </table>
```

My phpQuery code has no errors but displays nothing, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
require "phpQuery/phpQuery-onefile.php";


        // Load betting page
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.net/');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // Create phpQuery document with returned HTML
        $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($html);

        $articleDate = array();


        $surroundingTheArticles = $doc->find('table.articles');

            foreach( $surroundingTheArticles as $eachArticle)
            { 
             // get table rows    
             $articleDate[]  .= pq($eachArticle)->find('tbody:eq(0) tr:eq(1) td:eq(4)')->text();  // maybe first:a or something - don't know

            }

         print_r($articleDate[1]); 
         // find a way to print all article dates  

?>
```

Comment: can you edit in the array that is returned by the print_r(), that will determine how you need to loop it, or loop in loop if needed.

Comment: it displays nothing at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solution requires you to the simple_html_dom. you can get it [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = '
<table class="articles">
         <tbody>
           <tr>some text here maybe tags</tr>
           <tr>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td><a href="link.html">WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</a></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>   

      </table> 

      <table class="articles">
         <tbody>
           <tr>some text here maybe tags</tr>
           <tr>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td><a href="link.html">WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</a></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>   

      </table>


      <table class="articles">
         <tbody>
           <tr>some text here maybe tags</tr>
           <tr>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td> some text here maybe tags </td>
              <td><a href="link.html">WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</a></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>   

      </table>  
';

$html = str_get_html($html);

foreach($html->find('table[class=articles]') as $element){
    $result = $element->find('tr');
    $result = $result[1]->find('td');
    echo($result[4]); echo('<br>');
}


?>
```

Comment: on my phpED editor it is showing red under the [1], and i also get an error on this line - $result = $element->find('tr')[1]->find('td')[4]; the error is...  Undefined offset: 1

Comment: i edited the answer so that it work on older php version. I get this output:
WANT TO GET THIS TEXT
WANT TO GET THIS TEXT
WANT TO GET THIS TEXT

Comment: i finally managed to get it to work i had to change this line... $result = $result[1]->find('td'); to $result = $result[0]->find('td'); i would like to understand why this works with a [0] instead of [1] , seeing as im getting tr 2. does anybody know?

Comment: sorry thats strange, because by me its working like charm. may your html source looks slicty other than the provvided one. But if you happy with the result dont mind to accept the answer